# Clone/Migrating internal HDD to SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, migration, clonezilla

I have a internal 500GB HDD but with only 6GB used.
I want to migrate/clone this to a 240GB SSD that will be connected to my laptop through a HD dock.

What is the easiest way?

Comment: Actually it is much better to use that new SSD to replace the laptop internal HDD. The laptop will boot faster, and your battery will last longer.

Comment: thanks, Yes that is my plan to clone my current HD to SSD then put the SSD inside the laptop

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need a Live CD ([GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) should work fine)  that you can use to shrink your 500GB disk's partition. You'll need to shrink it down to less than the destination drive size. You should also create a partition of the same size on the SSD.

Then you will burn a [Clonezilla Live ISO](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) to a CD, boot from the CD, and clone the partitions from the source drive to the destination drive. You'll follow [these steps](http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone), except you'll choose "part_to_local_part". You may also need to copy the MBR using options under the "Advanced" menu. You can find more information about that [here](https://drbl.org/fine-print.php?path=./faq/2_System/88_mbr_related_options.faq#88_mbr_related_options.faq).

Answer (score 0):

If the SSD is equal or larger than the HDD, you can also use dd to clone the drive and exand the partition afterwards.
If sda is the source and sdb the target, it is as simple as:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=1024
```

Comment: The op has said their hdd is 500gb and the ssd is 240gb.